# gtk_entry from a dialog

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm trying to create a dialog that pops up when the user selects a specific entry from the combobox, it should record the user input and react accordingly.

here's my code so far:

```
void add_new_set(GtkWidget entry)
{
  g_print("howdy\n");
}

GtkWidget * dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("Message",container,GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,"OK", GTK_RESPONSE_NONE,NULL);
    GtkWidget * content_area = gtk_dialog_get_content_area (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    GtkWidget * entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), entry);
    g_signal_connect_swapped (dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (add_new_set),dialog);
    gtk_window_set_modal (GTK_WINDOW(dialog), TRUE);
    gtk_widget_show_all (dialog);
```

I need to get the input from the gtk_entry when the OK button is pressed, and perform a string comparison on that function.
the g_print line runs when the button is pressed.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that is absolutely the wrong signature for `add_new_set()`. Not only does it not follow the correct signature for `GtkDialog::response`, but it also passes a `GtkWidget` as a parameter. You should never have `GtkWidget` by itself, always `GtkWidget *` (a pointer to `GtkWidget`).

The correct signature for a `GtkDialog::response` is [given in the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog-response):

```
void
user_function (GtkDialog *dialog,
               gint       response_id,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

Second, you will need a way to pass `entry` in via `user_data`, either directly or indirectly, and for that `g_signal_connect_swapped()` is wrong. Use `g_signal_connect()` instead; the last argument of that becomes the `user_data`.

Finally, the function to get the text out of a GtkEntry is called, obviously enough, `gtk_entry_get_text()`. The pointer returned is only valid in the signal handler itself; you will need to copy it if you want to access it later, but for your needs you won't need to.

Good luck.